# Does Vue.js can import element-ui and Boostrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-4

I have imported element-ui components, but I may be need some common styles like reset.css and others in Boostrap.

Can they both exits in one project and not conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You cannot. In most cases, element-ui change the styles with class, But Bootstrap change the styles with both class and HTML tags, this's conflicting.

For example, you can find the following code in Bootstrap:

```
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: inherit;
}
```

In element-ui, there is a `reset.css` defined like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color:#1f2d3d;
    font-weight:inherit
}
```

So you can not use both Bootstrap and element-ui in one project without conflict.

Comment: How can I do if I want the **basic style** of `Bootstrap` as well as the **ui components** of `element-ui`?

Comment: @junlin why? if you want use bootstrap as Vue components, you can try bootstrap-vue https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/ .

Comment: i use bootstrap 4 reboot.scss with element ui, for now all ok

Comment: @Shaci Could you add more details please. How you did it? your main.js.